# Slow touch/swipe response on Lenovo Tablet P11

Tags: settings, touchscreen, lenovo

I recently purchased Lenovo Tablet P11 and I must say it's a great tablet with one exception. The scrolling and swiping in it is not so sensitive. I noticed I need to drag my finger for one centimeter until it registers the swipe.

I tried animation settings in dev options and I turned on pointer location so I know that screen actually sees all the touches pretty well. That makes me think that it's software issue.

I was curious if anyone encountered such problem on P11 or other devices? Maybe someone knows how to improve it.

Thank you!